# Abstract class cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, abstract-class

I had to create this point program a year ago, a year ago it worked fine. Now I have to revisit it and upon compiling and trying to run it I ran into the error of the fact that an abstract class cannot be instantiated. I have done some looking around online and figured out that some update or sort with Java has made it where the method of using `PointClass point1 = new PointClass();` is no longer valid and will through an error.

I have yet to find an answer for fixing the error when trying to instantiate the class using a driver program. I also saw that in order to use an abstract class now, a subclass must be present. The thing is is that due to the instructions of the program I cannot use a subclass. Only the driver and the point class.

The program is very simple, just declare some points and call them from the abstract class in order to print to the screen. I need some help on figuring out the updated method to make this work again without the instantiated error.

**The PointClass**

```
public abstract class PointClass {
    private int pointX;
    private int pointY;

    //set instance variables
    public PointClass() { this.pointX = 10; this.pointY = 10; }

    public PointClass(int x, int y){ this.pointX = x; this.pointY = y; }

    //make getters and setters
    public void setPointX(int x) { this.pointX = x; }
    public void setPointY(int y) { this.pointY = y; }
    public int getPointX() { return this.pointX; }
    public int getPointY() { return this.pointY; }

    //make string for format with driver
    public String toString() { return "x = " + this.pointX + " y = " + this.pointY; }

}
```

**The Driver**

```
public class PointTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println();

        PointClass point1 = new PointClass();         //set point1 as no argument 
        PointClass point2 = new PointClass(11, 24);  // set point2 as argument with x and y

        System.out.println("Point1: " + point1);  //display point1 from toString method
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Point2: " + point2); //display point2 from toString method
        System.out.println("---------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to instantiate an `abstract` class in Java. There is also no sense for your `Point` class to be defined as `abstract` since it does not have any abstract **methods**.

Comment: _Read the error message_.  Do you understand what `abstract` means?

Comment: Remove keyword `abstract` it's useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to remove the `abstract` keyword. There's no need for it. `Point` has no abstract methods.

If you can't do that for whatever reason, you can create inline anonymous classes by adding curly braces after each instantiation:

```
PointClass point1 = new PointClass() { };
PointClass point2 = new PointClass(11, 24) { };
```

By the way, your claim that this used to work is incorrect. It has never been possible to directly instantiate an abstract class. That is in fact the *entire point* of the keyword, to prevent a class from being instantiated.

Comment: instructions for this program are to use the abstract keyword and make an abstract class and then call from it. It worked a year ago with no errors.
Either way adding the {} helped, thank you for your input.